# Unable to extract rows based on a condition from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have just started learning about data.table. I created a sample data.table with below code.

```
dl <- data.table(v1 = rep(1:3), v2 = letters[1:5], v3 = sample(50,20))
```

I tried extracting rows with the condition where v1 = 2 `dl[v1 == '2']` and got the result but when trying to get rows with condition where v2 = b, I tried the following `dl[v2 == 'b']` and `dl[v2 == 'b',]` but I am getting an error

```
Error in setkeyv(..., physical = FALSE) : 
4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

Searched with the error and tried setting a key with `setkey(dl,v2)` (though I am not sure about setting keys) and still got error

```
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

Can someone please help me. I am running on windows 7 R v 3.2

Comment: update to latest `data.table` version and try again

Comment: Copying your code works without error in version 1.9.6

Comment: I am working on 1.9.6 itself. I just ran again as below. `> library(data.table)
data.table 1.9.6  For help type ?data.table
Warning message:
package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
> dl[v2 == 'b']
Error in setkeyv(..., physical = FALSE) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3`

Comment: @Yash are you trying in a fresh session?

Comment: @eddi yes I closed my current R session and opened again but got the same error

Comment: @Yash if it doesn't work for you with R 3.1+ and the [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table`, then please report it as a bug on `github` (adding `sessionInfo()`)

Comment: I was working on R v3.2 however i upgraded my R to v3.3 which was released yesterday and I got the result for `dl[ v2 == 'b']` . Thanks